# UIToolbar and UIImageView not showing up in simulator configured for 3.5" screen or actual 3.5" screen device

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiimageview, ios-simulator, uitoolbar, ios6.1

I'm having a problem with UIToolbar and UIImageView widgets. After setting them in IB and writing code for their respective events and functionalities, when i run the app in the simulator (set to 3.5" screen device) or on my 3.5" iPod touch, they don't show up at all. Then i repositioned the toolbar view slightly above and reconfigured the simulator to run as 4" screen device. It was working perfectly fine. Both the views (image view as well as toolbar at the bottom were showing up). I set the simulator back again as 3.5" device then. Again the views aren't appearing..Nether on the actual device (3.5" screen iPod touch) nor on the simulator.. Whats happening??? This is so strange.. Anybody knows how to fix this???

Comment: has someone faced this problem??

Comment: The image you are trying to set may be in another target.Each widget should have separate images with its targets.